# Shell script to extract text between two strings and modify and replace it in the same file

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have a markdown file which have src to respective images.

For example:

```
![Login Screen](0005_eppm_login_page.png)
```

I want to replace it as:

```
![Login Screen](../src/0005_eppm_login_page.png)
```

Comment: What efforts did you make on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got the problem of the slashes.. this one-liner may give you a hand:

```
 sed '/\[Login Screen\]/{s#(#(../src/#}'
```

In the sed one-liner, we can pick a separator other than `/` for `s(substitution)`, particularly, when the text/replacements containing slashes.

Comment: i want to replace all png starting with '(' and ending with '.png)'

Comment: i have multiple such instances 
|    1  | ![](0036_eppmicon_endeavour.png)| Endeavour
|    2  | ![](0020_eppmicon_project.png)| Project
|    3  | ![](0019_eppmicon_program.png)| Program
|    4  | ![](0024_eppmicon_operation.png),  | Op

Comment: what does my command do? you can pass the file to sed. extend the command as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
sed -i 's,\(!\[[^][]*](\)\([^()]*\.png)\),\1../src/\2,g' file
```

It will replace `![...](...\.png)` patterns with `![...](../src/...\.png)`.